# php mysql backup on linux using exec

Tags: php, mysql-backup

I am trying to use the exec() function to execute mysqldump file and store the backup file in a particular folder, but it doesn't appear in that folder. Any ideas on what is wrong with code?

```
exec('/usr/bin/mysqldump -h hostname -u root -psomepassword dbname > somepath/file.sql');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Test the command on the command line and see what happens. But If I were you I'd rather use the crontab or mysql replication.

Comment: Are you running this in localhost? many web hosting providers dont allow the use of exec function I agree with  edwardmp. If your idea is just backup your database using a crontab might be a better option.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Yes, I am trying to run it on localhost. And I also agree that crontab is a better option. I just wanted to test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access on the server try that:

```
sudo su www-data // Ubuntu, for other systems find out the user on which apache is running
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h hostname -u root -psomepassword dbname > somepath/file.sql
```

If that works, the problem is in php. If not, you know the problem because of the error message. But as already pointed out, crontab is a better solution for this.